# Can Windows Storage Server join an Azure AD

Tags: cloud, microsoft-office-365, windows-server-essentials

After a fatal hard disk crash (with backups, but lots of downtime), I'm seeking a less maintenance intensive setup for our non profit small business (previously Samba 4 AD, Zarafa Mail, Owncloud).

I have already setup Office 365 for mail and Owncloud replacement and tried out Windows 10 joining the Azure AD and in general like the setup. The problem is our local shared "folder" (~500GB data) which everybody uses and can't be moved to SharePoint / OneDrive. Instead of buying a new server, I thought that a NAS with Windows Storage Server could do the job.

I couldn't find an answer to the following questions:

- Can Windows Storage Server (2012 / 2016) join the Azure AD so that users can have different access permissions
- Can Windows Storage Server sync data with an Office 365 included OneDrive storage (or this there another solution)

The alternative would be to go for a real server and Windows Server 2016 Essentials which I think can do what I need...?

Comment: Why not just use onedrive?  What's the reason the files won't move?

Comment: From what I understand onedrive is not suited for shared folders accessed by ~5-10 people. No file locking, no immediate sync, not syncing at all when no Internet connection... Also we would need to equip every PC with about 1 TB for storing the synced folders...